# DynamoDB Architecture - Smaller Dataset with Complex Structure, or Larger Simpler Dataset

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We are building a game using DynamoDB. We have a list of about 50,000 items. These can be assigned to groups as part of the game. There are about 30 groups. We need to track the number of groups, by group and item.

I have set up a structure where each item has a structure, and that structure can potentially have each of the groups in it, containing a number, that can be incremented, so it looks something like this:

```
{ItemId: XYXYSY,
   Groups:{X:5,Y:10}
}
```

Which works just fine. The other way  I could do it of course, is to write the groupings out to a separate table:

```
{ItemID: XYSYSY, Timestamp: 12334567, Group: X}
```

So, I either need to increment the counters in the first mode, or write out a new record every time with the second.

The first means less data, and a nice package for retrieving the information by Item later. The second can grow infinitely, and is simpler.

At some point, I'll have to retrieve the entire thing and export it, or do it in increments.

I've been looking at Dynamo's performance model, and I'm trying to figure out if I am going to get myself in trouble with the first model. 50,000 keys, with a small amount of data for each record, is not going to be spread over a lot of partitions. At the same time, because it's a relatively small dataset, retrieved only by item id, and updated by item id, it should be quite fast. And with the second model, if the game becomes really popular, that table is going to grow like crazy, and it's really still only based around the same 50,000 keys. I'd probably add the timestamp as a range key.

Any thoughts on what is going to be more performant over time and load would be much appreciated, or even a completely different approach.

Comment: How much write and read throughput will you need on the table and per item? 50,000 items at 400 KB per item ([the max size per item](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html)) is only 20 GB which is only 2 partitions.

Comment: The problem is, it's a game. So, we could get 10 people, or 10 million people playing. At the low level, either will work fine. But I'm trying to think what'll happen if 10 million people pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

Data size is not the only thing that determines the number of partitions. Your throughput allocation will also affect the number of partitions if it is large. This is the case in both data models. For example, if you provision 3000 rps and 3000 wps on a new table, it will have exactly 4 partitions when you create it, with 750 wps and 750 rps allocated to each partition.

Assuming you go with the first model, this provisioning will allow you to update individual ItemIds at 750 transactions per second and a total of 3000 transactions per second across all item ids.

From this point forth, it seems like you need to figure out your load patterns to further determine if the first data model and the provisioning above are appropriate. Patterns like diurnal schedules, sustained versus bursty loads, write once read many, and write many read many may all affect your choice of data model.